# close button disappears while using modal fancybox(1.3.4)

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox with jquery for iframe. I set `modal` to `true` but the close button disappears. i read the documentation and  use the convention "When `true`, '`overlayShow`' is set to '`true`' and '`hideOnOverlayClick`', '`hideOnContentClick`', '`enableEscapeButton`', '`showCloseButton`' are set to '`false`'"  but close button disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Please read my article here. 
http://anvlpopescu.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/jquery-fancybox-modal-iframe-with-close-button/

There is an workaround for this.

Comment: Please try to incorporate a brief summary if your answer consists solely of a link.

Answer (score 1):

When "modal": true then You can append the close button in the after show event like

afterShow : function() {
        $('.fancybox-skin').append('');
    }

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You may need to read the documentation again (and slower perhaps) and understand that when `modal` is set to `true` (as you wrote above), then `showCloseButton` is set (automatically) to `false`.

`"showCloseButton": false` (`"modal": true`) means that the close button doesn't show up and that is the expected behavior.

Comment: @user1662658 : I guess I didn't make myself clear. If you set `"modal": true` then the close button will disappear and you won't be able to see it regardless that you set `"showCloseButton": true` ... that's normal, not an error, bug or issue. The only way to see the close button is setting `modal` to `false`.

Comment: @JFK I don't see this in the docs anywhere, but you appear to be correct.  What a frustrating "feature".  I wish I could have it be "modal" but also have `enableEscapeButton`, `showCloseButton`, and `hideOnOverlayClick` be true.

Comment: Oh I found this in the docs--I'd totally misunderstood 'modal': "When true, 'overlayShow' is set to 'true' and 'hideOnOverlayClick', 'hideOnContentClick', 'enableEscapeButton', 'showCloseButton' are set to 'false'".  I thought it would be more like jqueryui Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Place close image icon named `fancybox_sprite.png` in css directory.